# swiper js navigate isnt working when slider is set to autoplay

Tags: javascript, jquery, swiper.js

I am creating a slider with swiper js which will have autoplay with a speed of 6000 and a delay of 1. I want to navigate the previous and next slides as usual swiper js do. but I am having some problems. when I clicked the previous button the slide didn't stop and slide in the previous one. it first complete it slide and then when i click again then it goes to the previous one in 6 second

here is my code.

main.js

```
var swiper = new Swiper(".swiper", {
  loop: true,
  slidesPerView: "auto",
  spaceBetween: 10,
  centeredSlides: true,
  speed: 6000,
  autoplay: {
    delay: 1,
    disableOnInteraction: false,
  },
  disableOnInteraction: false,
  navigation: {
    nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
    prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev"
  },
});

$(".recorded-mobile-row-1").hover(() => {
  v = $('.recorded-row-1-content-slider').css('transform')
  v = `cursor: grab; transform: ${v}; transition-duration: 100ms;`
  $('.recorded-row-1-content-slider').attr('style', v)
  swiper.autoplay.stop()
},
  () => { //out
    v = $('.recorded-row-1-content-slider').css('transform')
    v = `cursor: grab; transform: ${v}; transition-duration: 1000ms;`
    $('.recorded-row-1-content-slider').attr('style', v)
    swiper.autoplay.start()
  }
);
```

index.html

```
<div class="recorded-mobile-row-1">
    <div class="recorded-mobile-slider-1 swiper">
        <div class="recorded-row-1-content-slider swiper-wrapper">
             <div class="c-recorded-poster-podcast swiper-slide"></div>
             <div class="c-recorded-poster-podcast swiper-slide"></div>
             <div class="c-recorded-poster-podcast swiper-slide"></div>
             <div class="c-recorded-poster-podcast swiper-slide"></div>
             <div class="c-recorded-poster-podcast swiper-slide"></div>
        </div>
      <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
      <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try: `disableOnInteraction: true` (Default value). No need for custom JS to stop swiper autoplay on hover (`pauseOnMouseEnter`).